# How to scan and connect to iBeacon using BLE services in the background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I have a iBeacon device with services advertising. I need to know to how to connect to the iBeacon from the iOS app in the background mode.

1. I know the service UUID of the iBeacon but I am not able to scan using serviceUUID in foreground and background mode.
2. If I scan for nil and filter using the name, working in the foreground but not in the background.

Please help me, I am new to iOS programming. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to share the relevant part of your code to improve upon

Answer (score 2):

**Don't confuse the ProximityUUID of the iBeacon transmission with a GATT Service UUID.**  While both are 16 byte identifiers typically represented in the same hex format, the two have entirely different meanings.   An iBeacon ProximityUUID cannot be used as a GATT Service UUID.

There is no requirement at all that a bluetooth beacon transmitting an iBeacon frame hosts any connectable GATT services.  While some manufacturers do offer a GATT service in their hardware beacons for configuring its identifiers as well as other purposes, the GATT Service UUID is typically not the same as the ProximityUUID.

If you want to do what you describe you need to:

1. Find out of your beacon manufacturer even hosts a GATT service at all.
2. It yes, find out what the GATT Service UUID is.  Again, it will typically not be the same as the iBeacon ProximityUUID.

If you cannot get the info from the manufacturer, you might be able to find it out by scanning in the foreground (without specifying the GATT Service UUID), then printing out the discovered GATT Service UUIDs for the device that you get by calling [discoverServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518706-discoverservices) on the `CBPeripheral` from the scan results.  You may find there are no services, which would give you a no answer to the first question above.

Once you have the above info, you can scan for the beacon in the background by specifying the GATT Service UUID when starting the scan. **In the background, you will not get results if you do not specify a GATT Service UUID**, and even if you do results will come much more slowly.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to describe my project in more detail-  I have a hardware device (peripheral) which hosts BLE GATT services and an iOS app (central). I am able to connect to the hardware with iOS app both in foreground and back ground mode. But I want the app to automatically connect to the hardware device in the scenario when the user kills the app. So I thought I can add iBeacon support to the hardware along with the GATT service. Please let me know if this helps?

Comment: Sure, you can use the iBeacon background detection to wake up your app (even after being killed), then connect using CoreBluetooth.  You just have to know the GATT Service UUID to start scanning for after wake up.

Comment: @ davidgyoung Is there any way other than using iBeacon to wake up my app. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not quickly, no.  You *can* use CoreBluetooth service discovery to wake up your app in the background, but it is much slower:  think minutes vs. seconds

Comment: I am receiving notifications from iBeacon hardware when the iOS app is killed. Now, I am trying to connect to the iBeacon in the background. I have the service UUID .I have added "central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID])" in the  centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager). Is there something I need to add

Comment: You do need to add the `bluetooth-central` background modes key in Info.plist.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for more info.

Comment: @ davidgyoung I have set the background mode keys and Request always and RequestInUse keys to my iOS app.  iOS app is receiving  notifications from the IBeacon (when the app is killed). However, iOS app is not able to establish  connection with the iBeacon services. Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you successfully get **CoreBluetooth** discovery callbacks in the background?  It is in this callback you need to establish your connection.

Comment: CoreBluetooth didDiscover is not called in the background and also in foreground. I am using scanForPeripherals(withServices: [uuid]). However it is connecting if I change  scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil) and connect by name in the foreground. Please let me know if there is any issue in iOS coding or in the iBeacon transmitted signals. I don't have bluetooth sniffer to check the packets

Comment: Please read my answer again.  If `scanForPeripherals(withServices: [uuid])` is not working in the foreground, and it is working without specifying the UUID, then that means you have the wrong UUID.